# Events in WinForms between two unrelated forms

Tags: winforms

Ok, I am just ramping up on winforms after having used WPF for the last 3 years. I need to fire an event from one form (when the customer information is updated) and have another form subscribe to that event and perform some processing to update the the customer information that is displayed if the customer that was updated matches the customer in the other form. I've only been able to find examples of doing this on forms that are child/parent or from a user control to the parent form, where the parent form has a reference to the child form that is subscribing to the event. I can't find any information on how I would set this up on two forms that are not related and do not have references to each other. I just want to fire an event from one form and pick it up in another. Seems like it should be pretty easy but I'm not having much luck. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

UPDATE: Here is what I have setup so far:

Object that contains the event and method to raise the event.

```
Public Class CustomerEvents

    Public Event CustomerInformationUpdatedEvent(ByVal customerId As Integer)

    Public Sub RaiseCustomerInformationUpdated(ByVal customerId As Integer)
        RaiseEvent CustomerInformationUpdatedEvent(customerId)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Form that is raising the event:

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click        
    Dim customerEvents As New CustomerEvents
    customerEvents.RaiseCustomerInformationUpdated(iCustomerID)
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Form that needs to subscribe to the event:

```
Private Sub myForm_Activated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated
    Dim customerEvents As New CustomerEvents
    AddHandler customerEvents.CustomerInformationUpdatedEvent, AddressOf HandleCustomerInformationUpdated
End Sub

 Private Sub HandleCustomerInformationUpdated(ByVal customerid As Integer)
      ' Processing
 End Sub
```

But the HandleCustomerInformationUpdated is never being hit. What am I doing wrong?? Thanks!

Comment: Using `As New` cannot work, you get a new instance of the class that nobody could possibly have subscribed the event for yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option would be to use a pub/sub type service you can pass in to both forms.  Basically create an object that has an event, and a method that triggers that event.  Then, the form that needs to notify others can take in that object and call the trigger method when appropriate, and the other forms can all attach to that object.

**EDIT**

The following incomplete service declaration should give some ideas.

```
public class EventService {
    public EventHandler MyEvent {add;remove;}
    public void TriggerMyEvent() {
        MyEvent();
    }
}
```

It could then be used by creating a single copy and passing the EventService instance into the constructor for the forms.  The publishing form would then just do `myEventServiceInstance.TriggerMyEvent()`, and the subscribing forms, on creation would register to `myEventServiceInstance.MyEvent;`

Ideally you would use an IoC container to pass a single instance in and handle the object lifetime, but that is outside the scope of this issue.

Comment: Thanks, that is kind of what I am thinking too I was just not sure how to implement it. I shouldn't have an issue creating the object with the event and method that triggers it but I get a little confused on how I would actually fire it and then catch it on the other forms. Can you throw up some pseudo code or an example? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again. This line gives me pause: "It could then be used by creating a single copy and passing the EventService instance into the constructor for the forms." because these forms are completely unrelated and not opened from anywhere near the same place. I guess I could have a module with an instance in it that I pass to the forms constructors?

Comment: Yea, that is where you get into using something like Unity to handle the dependency injection. Whether or not you need a separate module depends on whether you want to be able to do the publishing across modules, and exactly how your dependencies are setup right now.  If all of the subscribing components are in modules that are dependent upon the publisher module, then you can probably just include the service in the publisher module.

Comment: In the update you posted, the problem is that your shortcut for getting instances doesn't work with non-static properties.  You could potentially change the event property to be static, so that your individual instances all use that static event.  That would fix the current code. It is a little uglier than dependency injection, but if your use case is simple it may not hurt too bad down the road.

Edit: Static = Shared in VB.  You'd make the event shared.

Comment: Thanks. I created a module that has a new instance of the event class. I use that module to raise and subscribe to the events and it is working great. Where is the correct way to clean up (unsubscribe) from events in a winform?

Comment: The dispose method usually works fine.  I've seen people advocate for also doing it in the Close method as well, but that goes against the standard conventions for IDisposable and typically doesn't provide performance benefits sufficient to warrant it.

Comment: Thanks again, I'd like to look into dependency injection rather than just having a module with static methods/properties. For my use case and the time that I am allowed to work on this, the module works great and the event is being unsubscribed to in the forms dispose method. Thanks again!